# Can I declare 2 desired_cap in 1 script? One for hybrid app and one for the Chrome app?

Tags: python, android, selenium, appium-android, desiredcapabilities

I have a hybrid app with redirects on the chrome browser.

In order to make appium recognize both apps, is there a possibility to declare a double  `desired_cap`?

I want to make the script to click on one of the hybrid app button, then after the redirect to chrome is done, a verification of the chrome page should be done (so we can know that the redirect was done correctly) and then we have the `driver.back()` which will lead us back to the hybrid testing app.

I know is wrong what I've wrote, but can't find the right way.. got the error that the `__second__` is not defined.

My example:

[image]

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the Desired Capabilities and also it is not possible during the session.
You must switch between the context of session (WEB_VIEW or NATIVE):
When the chrome opened do this:

```
driver.switch_to.context['WEB_VIEW_chrome]
```

Check your verifications and then you can change the context to the Native to continue on your android application:

```
driver.switch_to.context['NATIVE_APP]
```

Here is my full answer on this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284044/7302505

Comment: Hi,
It seems that the statement has no effect 
same with the ones from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148881/appium-v1-17-1-unable-to-switch-webview-context-in-ios/62284044#62284044