# what are the appium capabilities for webviews in android?

Tags: android, typescript, appium-android, chrome-options, desiredcapabilities

I have tried using below capabilities

```
{
      maxInstances: 1,
      browserName: '',
      appiumVersion: '1.18.2',
      platformName: 'android',
      platformVersion: '10.0',
      deviceName: 'device',
      webviewConnectTimeout: '90000',
      chromeOptions: {args: ['--windowTypes=webview']},
      safariLogAllCommunication: true,
      enableWebviewDetailsCollection: true,
      ensureWebviewsHavePages: true,
      showChromedriverLog: true,
      app: './android/app/build/outputs/apk/',
      noReset: true,
      autoWebview: true,
}
```

but still not able to fetch the webview url. Below is the snippet of my code

```
let contexts = driver.getContexts();
console.log(contexts);
driver.switchContext('WEBVIEW_be.belgacom.hello');
console.log(driver.getPageSource());
console.log(driver.getUrl());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By meaning WebView if you want to open a web application/website in chrome app in android, these are the mandatory capabilities:

```
{'platformName': 'Android,'udid': YOUR DEVICE UDID, 
'appActivity': 'com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main', 
'appPackage': 'com.android.chrome',
'chromedriverExecutable': PATH OF CHROME DRIVER, 
'deviceName': ANY NAME,'chromeOptions': {'w3c': False},'autoGrantPermissions': True}
```

You should switch to WEB_VIEW in case of doing action on the chrome mobile.

The syntax is in Python:

```
driver.switch_to.context['NATIVE_APP]   #appium chrome driver
driver.switch_to.context['WEB_VIEW_chrome']    # selenium chrome driver
```

Here is my full answer about context switching:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284044/7302505

Answer to the comment:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how can i add chrome options in capabilities as to the way the syntax should be? as i am giving it this way chromeOptions: {args: ['--w3c=false']

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the answer to this question, If your problem is resolved please check the tick :)

Answer (score 0):

for Java:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.setExperimentalOption("w3c",false); 
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).